# Two versions of same library in one app

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I have two versions (with almost identical API) of same shared library. I must use them in same application. I know how to resolve name clashes in the headers -- I will just import them like this

```
namespace version1 {
    #include "version1/library.h"
}

namespace version2 {
    #include "version2/library.h"
}
```

I do not know though how I resolve linking clashes -- library is dynamically linked. First version creates following structure in custom lib folder:

```
libsomething.so -> libsomething.so.2
libsomething.so.2 -> libsomething.so.0.8.31.1
libsomething.so.0.8.31.1
```

second one:

```
libsomething.so -> libsomething.so.2
libsomething.so.2 -> libsomething.so.0.8.32
libsomething.so.0.8.32
```

My target environment is Linux machine.

Context:

I have source of libraries but they are downloaded and compiled automatically so I would like to avoid changing anything in CMakeProject of those libs but I can do it if other options are to complicated. I would prefer solution that does changes to those libs after compilation e.g. change soname. But again if I have to do some complicated stuff in app code to use those libs I prefer doing changes to these libs project and maintaining them (because version can change but there will always be two of them -- one version will probably be set forever and never updated so I would prefer to change this non changing version).

Comment: Namespaces won't resolve the link problem, unless you rebuild both versions of the library so the functions are defined in respective namespaces as well.   The more usual approach is, for each dynamically linked library, to set up a data structure containing a set of pointers to functions in that library.

Answer (score 0):

> My target environment is Linux machine.

It appears that both versions of the libraries, based on the symlinks, have the same `SONAME`, namely `libsomething.so.2`.

This completely precludes linking them to the same executable, and loading both of them at runtime using Linux's runtime loader. It does not have this capability.

The only option I see is for your executable to load each library manually, using the [dlopen(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/dlopen.3.html) library call. Afterwards you will need to use [dlsym(3) or dlsymv3(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/dlsym.3.html) to find the address of each function, in each loaded library, and invoke it indirectly.

Note that `dlsym()` and `dlsymv3()` take the mangled version of each function name. It's going to be up to you to figure out what the mangled names of each function are.

Nobody claimed that this is going to be easy, but this is doable when there are absolutely no other options, whatsoever.

Comment: Is changing the so name by changing the filename to something like libsomeghingver1.so.2 and libsomeghingver2.so.2 enough to make it easier or do I need to recompile libraries if I change soname?

Comment: I added a bit more context in the end of question.

Comment: Yes, if you change the name of the library, that will be enough.

Comment: Could you edit your question then to tell me what I have to do after changing the name of the library? After all if I link with both libraries both of them will have same classes and methods. So if I call e.g. obj.f() from namespace version1 then linker still will not know from which library it should link. For my ideal solution would be if I do not have to use load functions using dlsym but generally I would like to write "normal" function calls.

Comment: No, you will not be able to link with them, if they have the same name and classes (well, you actually will, but the references from your executable will get resolved only to one of the libraries' symbols). This presumes that all names and classes are different. If the names and classes are the same, then dlopen-based approach is the only solution.

Comment: What if I change ver1 library to static library and split my application to two static libraries: application_library_1 and application_library_2. Application_library_1 would link statically with libraryver1 and application_library_2 with link dynamically with libraryver2. Then I would have some main part of my application app that links with application_library_1 and application_library_2.

Comment: Static libraries on link with other static libraries, which is equivalent with inserting the 2nd lib into the 1st one. Static libraries do not link with shared libraries.